# Sql Query runs in phpmyadmin, doesnt work in php

Tags: php, sql, database

Hello i have a small php query i run that updates multiple rows in my table.

```
SET @rank = 0;
UPDATE Summoner_Champions SET Rank = (@rank := @rank + 1)
WHERE Champion_ID=0
ORDER BY Total DESC
```

When i try and use the following php code, it doesnt work

```
$Ranker_Sql = "SET @rank = 0;
                UPDATE Summoner_Champions SET Rank = (@rank := @rank + 1)
                WHERE Champion_ID=0
                ORDER BY Total DESC";
if ($Conn_Info->query($Ranker_Sql) === TRUE) {
    echo " Total Updated ";
} 
else {
    echo mysqli_error($Conn_Info);
    echo "Total Not Updated";
}
```

I tried using an alternative query and it worked, such as a super simple update, so the connection info is correct.

Thank you for reading, and for the help :)

Edit 1: Tried the query using PDO, still did not seem to work. Tried to find resources online that could help me with using sql variables in php sql queries but alas found nothing.

Comment: what error return from mysql?

Comment: In case you are working with PDO: UPDATE-Statements need you to rather use `$Conn_Info->execute()` instead of `$Conn_Info->query()`

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'UPDATE Summoner_Champions SET Rank = (@rank := @rank + 1) WHERE Champion_I' at line 2

Comment: serjoscha, i was using PDO in some places but in others i wasn't, other update statements are working written in the same manner :(

Answer (score 1):

Solved, i had to declare the sql variable in a seperate sql query, then i was free to use it in my query :).

Like this.

```
$Pre_Sql = "SET @rank =0";
$dbc->query($Pre_Sql);
$Normal_Sql = "UPDATE Summoner_Champions SET Rank = (@rank := @rank + 1)
                WHERE Champion_ID=0
                ORDER BY Total DESC";
$dbc->query($Normal_Sql);
```